# How do I import classes from a package in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package

I have a package folder called `snake` with .java files and I am trying to import a specific class from it for example `Move`.

I have placed the folder into the same project folder as the src folder I am currently working with, but when I tried to do an `import snake.Move;`               I get an error message saying that the ***import cannot be resolved***.

Did I store the folder in the wrong directory? Or am I missing a step?

Comment: Do you see the file listed in the project viewer?  Sometimes you have to configure paths in Eclipse which can be a pain.

Comment: A snapshot of your eclipse would be very helpful :)

Comment: The folder is listed in the package explorer, and the .java files in the folder are displayed with that "paper with a hollow J" icon, instead of the solid coloured J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `.java` files are registered in a package that has the same name as the folder you use inside the `src` Eclipse project folder.

In other words, they have to start with:

```
package snake;
```

.. if they are located in the `src/snake` folder.

Your source files need to be in what Eclipse calls a `Source Folder`. By default, for a new java project, `src` is created and marked as source folder. If you've just pasted the folder with your sources from the filesystem into the project folder, you will see that in Eclipse, `src` and you folder look differently (`src` has some brown blocks in it, marking it as a source folder). You need to register your folder as a source folder as well.

You have 2 methods to set source folders:

1. Right click on your project and select `New > Source Folder` and
   enter the name of your simple folder. Once you click Finish, you
   will see your regular folder be marked just like `src` is and
   properly registered as a source folder.
2. Right click on your project and select `Properties` then select the
   tab `Java Build Path` and the first sub-tab `Sources`. There you can
   see the currently registered source folders and you can press `Add Folder` to register some more folders (from your project's main folder) as source folders.

However, keep in mind that it's generally easier and a best practice to have only 1 source folder, which is `src` and to put all your code inside it, organized by packages.

Comment: I have the folders in the same project folder but not in the src folder. Do I need them to be in the src folder? And yes, they do start with `package snake;`

Comment: I've updated my answer with explanations about Eclipse's Source Folders and how to properly register your `snake` folder as a source folder. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Package folder should be inside the same directory as the java file importing it.

so if the main.java importing the snake package they should have the same path

src/snake

src/game.java

If they are not in the same folder than better keep them in the same folder(If it is fine with your program) cause it's easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

under *src* folder create a folder named "snake" then put your *move* file there